# Power BI Format Function Text Sort Issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a Measure column in Power BI. The Measure converts the Revenue from one currency to another, dependent on a switch. However, this results in the column being sorted alphabetically instead of numeric.

Here's the Measure column switch:

```
SWITCH(TRUE(), [Valutakurser Selected Currency]="EUR", FORMAT([COLUMN NAME] / VALUES(Valutakurser[CurrencyRate]), "€#,##0.00"), [COLUMN NAME]]="DKK", FORMAT([COLUMN NAME]] * VALUES(Valutakurser[CurrencyRate]), "#,##0.00 kr."))
```

This results in the value being converted to a string, with the currency symbol/text added.

I have access to the Revenue in number-format, but I cannot figure out how to order the Measure column by a different column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic format strings to keep the value as a number:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-dynamic-format-strings

> Dynamic format strings overcome an inherent disadvantage of using the
> FORMAT function. That is, with FORMAT even numeric data types are
> returned as a string, which may not work with visuals that require
> numeric values, like charts. When using dynamic format strings, the
> measure keeps its data type and isn't forced to change to a string
> data type.

Comment: Bacci the sorting works, which is great. However, I'm experiencing problems with the value that gets shown.

I've made this Switch for the Format:
SWITCH([Exchange Rate Currency],
    "EUR", FORMAT([VALUE NAME] / VALUES(Valutakurser[Exchange Rate]), "€#,##0.00"),
    "DKK", FORMAT([VALUE NAME] * VALUES(Valutakurser[Exchange Rate]), "#,##0.00 kr.")
)

None of the numbers are formatted correctly, and some of them doesn't even match the value anymore. Fx 4027248.61 is formatted to 44.027.2492724861 kr, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Bacci ignore my comment. I realized I needed to remove the whole "FORMAT" lines inside the switch. Now it works. Thanks for helping out!